# How can I create an arbitrary number of columns of random vectors?

Tags: r, dataframe

I often need to write something like

```
sample_size = 10^4
my_data <- data.frame(x1 = runif(sample_size, 0,3), x2 = runif(sample_size, 0,3), x3 = runif(sample_size, 0,3), x4 = runif(sample_size, 0,3))
```

in order to test some statistical models. For example,

```
error <- rnorm(sample_size, 0, 0.1)
y <- with( my_data, 2*x1+0.1*(x2 + x3 + x4)) + error
my_model <- lm(y ~ ., data = my_data)
```

Since `my_data` is used as input to `lm`, it has to be a data frame (or a list).

I wonder if invoking `runif` 4 times is the right way to do this, or if there are better solutions. I tried

```
my_data <- matrix(4*runif(sample_size, 0,3), sample_size, 4, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("x", 1:4)))
my_data <- as.data.frame(my_data)
```

But it doesn't seem so readable to me.

Comment: `as.data.frame(replicate(4, runif(sample_size, 0, 3)))`. Though you may be better off leaving it as a matrix.

Comment: @Gregor `replicate` is great, I didn't think of it. I need `my_data` to store the predictors of a linear regression, so I need it to be a data frame. I will edit the question to make this apparent.

Comment: No need to complicate your question when the only difference is whether or not the code you need is wrapped in `as.data.frame`. I *would* recommend editing your question to something more like "How can I create an arbitrary number of columns of random vectors?" As-is, the question comes off as non-concrete and possibly opinion-based.

Comment: @Gregor sorry, I don't understand your first sentence (I don't know what you mean "my code is wrapped in `as.data.frame`" ), but I tried to follow your suggestions about editing the question. Is it better now?

Comment: Good edits - better question. Questions that are "what's the *best* way to do something" often get closed as opinion-based, and I think you're in the clear now. What I meant in the first sentence is that data frame/matrix conversion is so easy (`as.data.frame`) that it's not worth being specific in your question about what the result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Let's say you want `ncol` columns, here are some good ways:

```
ncol = 4
sample_size = 10

replicate(ncol, runif(sample_size, 0, 3))
matrix(runif(sample_size * ncol, 0, 3), ncol = ncol)
sapply(1:ncol, function(x) runif(sample_size, 0, 3))
```

These create matrices which you can, of course, convert to data frames as needed. The differences are  minor. `replicate` is essentially a nice wrapper for `sapply`. The direct `matrix` method may be *slightly* faster, but probably the difference is a few milliseconds.

Comment: This is very cool, but I need also names for the columns. If `mat` is the matrix built by one of your methods, are you suggesting to do something like `data_mat <- as.data.frame(mat, col.names = paste0("x", 1:ncol))` ?

Comment: hmmm, no, you are clearly not suggesting to do that, because it doesn't work. How do I add the column names? I could use `dimnames`, but it only works with `matrix`

Comment: There are lots of ways to add names to a data frame. You can use `names(data) <- ...` or `set.names()`.

Comment: Using `dimnames` is also an option. All these methods create matrices - if you set the dim names of the matrix before converting to data frame, the names will be preserved. I would probably just do `names(df) <- paste0("x", 1:ncol)` after the fact.